# Mapping between matrices

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix, mapping

I have 2 matrices:

```
list_alpha = [['a'], 
              ['b'], 
              ['c'], 
              ['d'], 
              ['e']]

list_beta = [['1', 'a', 'e', 'b'],
             ['2', 'd', 'X', 'X'], 
             ['3', 'a', 'X', 'X'],
             ['4', 'd', 'a', 'c'],
```

And my goal is if a letter from list_alpha is in a sublist of list_beta, then the first element of that line in list_beta (the #) is added to the correct line in list_alpha.
So my output would be:

```
final_list = [['a', '1', '3', '4'], 
              ['b', '1'], 
              ['c', '4'], 
              ['d', '2', '4'], 
              ['e', '1']]
```

But I'm pretty new to python and coding in general and I'm not sure how to do this. Is there a way to code this? Or do I have to change the way the data is stored in either list?

---

Edit:

Changing list_alpha to a dictionary helped!

Final code:

```
dict_alpha = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'd': [], 'e':[]}
list_beta = [['1', 'a', 'e', 'b'],
             ['2', 'd', 'X', 'X'],
             ['3', 'a', 'X', 'X'],
             ['4', 'd', 'a', 'c'],
             ['5', 'X', 'X', 'e'],
             ['6', 'c', 'X', 'X']]
for letter in dict_alpha:
    for item in list_beta:
        if letter in item:
            dict_alpha.get(letter).append(item[0])
print(dict_alpha)
```

Comment: I would convert list_alpha into a dictionary of letter->empty list e.g., `{"a": [], "b":[] ... }`, then iterate through each list in list_beta and append numbers to the lists in the dictionary as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict_alpha` as same as `list_alpha` , then fix your for loop.

**For example:**

```
dict_alpha = [['a'],
              ['b'], 
              ['c'], 
              ['d'], 
              ['e']]

list_beta = [['1', 'a', 'e', 'b'],
             ['2', 'd', 'X', 'X'],
             ['3', 'a', 'X', 'X'],
             ['4', 'd', 'a', 'c'],
             ['5', 'X', 'X', 'e'],
             ['6', 'c', 'X', 'X']]

for al in dict_alpha:
    for bt in list_beta:
        for i in range(1, len(bt)):
            if (bt[i] == al[0]):
                al.append(bt[0])

print(dict_alpha)
```

**Output:**

```
[['a', '1', '3', '4'], 
['b', '1'], 
['c', '4', '6'], 
['d', '2', '4'], 
['e', '1', '5']]
```

**Hope to helpful!**